# How to Capture div/table where Webpage gets refreshed continuously(to get live data) Imacro code(933)

Tags: imacros

I am tring to capture a table using CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT. My webpage is continuously getting refreshed as it gives live records due to which m facing problem, as 
Imacro waits for webpage to get loaded. Can anyone please help me I am very new to Imacro and coding.

My code looks like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8850919 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=about:home
URL GOTO=http://10.1.0.100/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:txt_usr_name CONTENT=*****
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD ATTR=ID:txt_password CONTENT=*******
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=ID:form0 ATTR=ID:btn_logon
FRAME NAME="bottomLeftFrame"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Maintenance
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Statistics
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:list_table&TXT: CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
FRAME NAME="bottomLeftFrame"
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:t_menu_logout
```

I have tried this method in my other webpages it worked perfectly as expected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this works. You have to put the download folder location in order for it to work.

```
VERSION BUILD=8850919 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=about:home
URL GOTO=http://10.1.0.100/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:txt_usr_name CONTENT=*****
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD ATTR=ID:txt_password CONTENT=*******
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=ID:form0 ATTR=ID:btn_logon
FRAME NAME="bottomLeftFrame"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Maintenance
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Statistics
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\ FILE=screenshot.png
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:list_table&TXT: CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
FRAME NAME="bottomLeftFrame"
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:t_menu_logout
```